# Refresh and call function in script

Tags: javascript

So I have a function in a script called `start()` and at the end of the `start()` function I will ask if the user if s/he wants to play again. If they do want to play again, i want the page to refresh and im doing this using `location.reload()` and then i want to start from the beginning of the start function again. However, when i simply do this...

```
location.reload();
start();
```

it doesn't refresh the page. I was wondering if there is another way for me to go about doing this?

More Info:

this is a black jack game that i am creating for learning purposes.

start function is called when a button is clicked.

in the start function, the dealer and player cards will be shown and then the player has option to either hit or hold.

I wanted all of the things done in the start function erased on the webpage and i done it by refreshing the page(it was the simplest way to me). and then i wanted to call the start function again when the page is refreshed and the user selects okay on the confirm dialog box that he wants to play again.

**EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/MAbgW/7/ my code is here. pls help if you're free. seems like an easy fix i think i might just be saying it in a confusing way.

Comment: We need more information on this. How is `start()` initially called?

Comment: start() surely won't execute, the page is after all reloaded ?

Comment: are there any errors in the browser console? press F12 to bring thatup in chrome. Is your code even making to the location.reload();

Comment: Why do u need to reload the page? Can't u simple call `start()` again? Or, better yet, use a do/while loop and if user replies Yes - simple return to the beginning of the loop

Comment: @mituw16 it is going to the location.reload(); it refreshes the page and everything is good. But then to start the game again they would need to press the start button. I wanted it so that if the user selects ok for the "Play again?" box that pops up when the game ends, it automatically starts a new game without the user pressing the start button again

Comment: You can view my answer. It prompts, and reloads the current page on a selection of "OK".

Comment: I looked at your code, and I don't understand the way you have the prompts laid out, or exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but I was able to get it to stop the rest of the function by utilizing `end;` in your `refresh` function.

Comment: @NicholasHazel Thanks for your help. Still doesn't work but really appreciate your time in trying.

Comment: I think what you need to do is get a more global perspective and put all of your conditionals for either "refresh the page" && "continue down the path" inside the same function. It's confusing to have a bunch of tiny functions all over the place :-) If you look at my post, the solution works, but with scattered functions everywhere they won't talk to each other, so you'd be forced to write all kinds of complicated code to target each function, or set a variable to determine if it SHOULD or SHOULDN'T continue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried...

```
location.reload(true);
```

Alternatively, you could do...

```
location.href = location.href;
```

This would simply send them back to the same URL.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but this doesnt start the start() function again.

Comment: Wouldn't that reset all of the other variables that were defined in other parts of the function?

Comment: You can't keep the variable state if you want to refresh the page. You would need to store the variable states somewhere (cookies, session, datastore, etc)...

Answer (score 0):

**This should do it. Reloads the page and stops the rest of the `start()` function, unless the user is done.**

#### EDIT:

```
function start(){
    alert("Going...");
    var cont = confirm("Do you want to continue?");
    if(cont){ location.reload(); end; } // notice the end

    alert("Let me know if you see this when you select OK");
}
start();
```

#### This code will work: http://jsfiddle.net/MAbgW/9/

Comment: this doesnt refresh the page, it will go to the start function and will have the previous things that were in the start function still on the page. Thanks for the quick reply

Comment: This still doesnt refresh the page for some reason it refreshes the page after it ends the start() function

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to reload page. Restart your function in a loop like this:

```
function start() {

    do {

        alert('The Game is On!');

    } while (confirm('Do you want to play again?'))

}

start();
```

*Do not* use page reload as a means of reinitializing data - rather initialize them at the beginning of your start function (first thing inside of `do` block in code above)

**Demo with data init: http://jsfiddle.net/e9W6q/1/**

Comment: I've tried this and some of the previous game's data is still on the webpage and i found refreshing the page the best way for me to get rid of all of the data on the page and then starting a new game

Comment: I think you better find out how is data initialized on page reload and do that inside of loop above. That said - how is the game starts on initial load? Do you call `start()` somehow?